# How do I make a flexible width on an element with absolute position?

Tags: html, css, width, css-position, absolute

The width of `.in` is automatically the width of `.three`. The amount of text in `.in` is flexible with each list element. I need the width of `.in` to adjust according to the amount of text in it.

`min-width` will keep it from being too small, but there is extra space when there is only a few words. `width:auto` and `height:auto` don't change anything. Turning `display` to `inline-block` or `table` doesn't work either, maybe because it's `position:absolute`?

Right now it's the same width of it's parent and really tall, which looks weird.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p class="one">One</p>
            <p class="two">Two</p>
            <a class="three">Three<p class="in">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p></a>
            <p class="four">Four</p>
            <p class="five">Five</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p class="one">One</p>
            <p class="two">Two</p>
            <a class="three">Three<p class="in">Lorem ipsum</p></a>
            <p class="four">Four</p>
            <p class="five">Five</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`.in` is positioned relative to `.three`. It hovers to the bottom right.

```
.three{
    position:relative;
    width:80px;
}
.in{
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10px 30px 30px 30px;
    left:35px;
    max-width:400px;
    padding:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Please provide `fiddle` for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Is that you wanted?

```css
.three {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.in {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px 30px 30px 30px;
    left: 35px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p class="one">One</p>
            <p class="two">Two</p>
            <a class="three" href="#">Three<p class="in">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p></a>
            <p class="four">Four</p>
            <p class="five">Five</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p class="one">One</p>
            <p class="two">Two</p>
            <a class="three" href="#">Three<p class="in">Lorem ipsum</p></a>
            <p class="four">Four</p>
            <p class="five">Five</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change your max-width to width:500px; or something like that then it should just expand and show all the text. 
[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/midwackcan/xja2e8x6/2/)

```
.in{
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10px 30px 30px 30px;
    left:35px;
    width: 500px;/<!--This is what you have to change-->
    padding:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    z-index:10;
}
```